# How to fix net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME on Sketchware webview app?

Tags: android, webview

I have an android webview app,  build with sketchware.  But,  when I attempt to open mail:to link,  whatsapp link,  etc,  it returns net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME.

I have search for the solution for this problem online,  but all of them requires Android studio.

Can I have a 'sketchware'  solution for this problem please?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `mailto:` and not `mail:to`?